# dialog based decisions in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, zenity

i am trying to write a little bash script that dose different things based on some gui questions.

this is how far i got right now:

```
[Timomey@timomeyswetab ~]$ TEST=`zenity --question`; echo test=$TEST
test=
[Timomey@timomeyswetab ~]$ TEST=`zenity --question`; echo test=$TEST
test=
[Timomey@timomeyswetab ~]$
```

problem is that it isnt working as expected. there should some difference in the TEST variable but i cant see any. What am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: `TEST='dada'; echo "test=$TEST"`. Will work with `ls` too.

Answer (score 4):

`zenity` doesn't write the result of your choice to std-out.  Try it for yourself by running it on the command line:

```
$ zenity --question
$
```

As you can see, nothing is shown, which is why your `TEST` variables are empty.

Instead, `zenity` returns the value of `--question` as its exit status.  This can be viewed (in bash) with the `$?` internal variable.

```
$ zenity --question
```

Select the 'No' button:

```
$ echo $?
$ 1
```

As explained in the man page, 0 signifies 'Yes', 1 signifies 'No' and 5 signifies the command timed out.

Your command should therefore be:

```
$ zenity --question; echo test=$?
$ test=1
```

Note that different `zenity` commands have different behaviours.  As the man page explains, the `--entry` command does send its output to std-out:

```
$ zenity --entry
$ Test 1..2..3..
```

Therefore your tests would work with this particular command.